Use of time average in the Virial Theorem
I was trying to understand how to derive the Virial Theorem. I found a YouTube video explanation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwsmyYnyuj8) where the person took a time average of the second derivative of rotational inertia, which was 0. I understood this. But I did not understand how she equated this to the second derivative itself. On one hand you have a rate of change, on the other a constant value. I tried looking at other PDF explanations but they did not explain this either.
Wikepedia says 'In statistical mechanics, the virial theorem provides a general equation that relates the average over time of the total kinetic energy of a stable system of discrete particles, bound by a conservative force with that of the total potential energy of the system.' so I know that it is supposed to relate the average over time, but we did this for the double derivative of inertia, which is not equal to the total kinetic energy. This further confuses me.
Please keep in mind that I am still in high school, so I haven't studied statistical mechanics. You may have to spell out some things that are trivial to you.

Title/name of YouTube video in case of linkrot? Which minute?

The link is in the question. At 2:15.

(Reference for others: the video in question is titled "The Virial Theorem: Derivation and Example" and can be found on a Youtube channel called "AstroNaught".)
To answer the question:
The confusion is probably a result of sloppy notation in the video. The person in the video does not actually equate the time average and the quantity itself but just drops the brackets denoting average. A more formal version of this would be:
As in the video, we start with $$ Q = \sum_i p_i \cdot r_i \Rightarrow \frac{dQ}{dt} = \sum_i (\frac{dp_i}{dt} r_i + p_i \frac{dr_i}{dt}) $$ and show that this can be written as $$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2I}{dt^2} = U + 2K $$ where I is the moment of inertia $I = \sum_i m_i r_i^2$ and $U$ and $K$ are the potential and kinetic energies, respectively. (If I got it right, you understood these parts.) Note that these are all functions of time, only the total energy in the system ($E = K + U$) is constant. Now we take the time average of the equation on both sides. As shown in the video, the left hand side vanishes, and since the average is linear, the right hand side just yields the sum of averages: $$ 0 = \langle U \rangle + 2 \langle K \rangle $$ The virial theorem follows as $ \langle K \rangle = - \frac{1}{2} \langle U \rangle $, i.e. the average total kinetic energy in the system is minus one half the average potential energy. As stated in your Wikipedia quote, this equation relates only time averages, not the instantaneous energies. In the video (and many other sources) the average is implied but not explicitly written.
The more general version of the theorem for polynomial potentials is $$ \langle K \rangle = \frac{k}{2} \langle U \rangle $$ where $k$ is the degree of the polynomial. In the case of Newtonian gravity $k = -1$ as above.

Thanks! I get it now.

I prefer to think of the Virial Theorem as an umbrella name for a set of related concepts.
I recommend the discussion of the Virial theorem by John Baez.
John Baez points out that one aspect of the virial theorem is already present in the case of a bound system consisting of two objects, moving around the common center of mass in circular motion. In that very simple case there is no need to average, because the motion is a constant circular motion.
Starting from that simplest case one can generalize to systems with multiple particles, and to averaging-over-time of non-circular orbits.

The virial theorem has two aspects: interconversion between kinetic energy and potential energy, and averaging. Those two aspects are independent.
In this answer I will discuss the interconversion aspect.
For the averaging aspect I refer to the discussion by John Baez.


I start with considering the following general expression that expresses what many force laws have in common: the attracting force is proportional to a power of the mutual distance, with $k$ used as coefficient of that proportionality.
$$ F = k \ r^p \tag{1}  $$
In the case of Hooke's law the magnitude of the force is in linear proportion to the (mutual) distance. That is, in a situation where an interaction is according to Hooke's law we have that the exponent $p$ of Eq. (1) is 1: $F=kr$.
In the case of the Coulomb interaction (electrostatic force) and newtonian gravity the exponent is -2: $F=k/r^2$
In any bound system: the attractive force is providing the required centripetal force that sustains circumnavigating motion. For a given circumnavigating velocity $v$ the required centripetal force is $ \frac{m v^2}{r} $
The general expression then is:
$$ \frac{m v^2}{r} = k \ r^p \tag{2}  $$
At this point we take advantage of the fact that force-that-sustains-circumnavigating-motion and kinetic energy have the quantity $m v^2$ in common. We multiply both sides of (2) with $\tfrac{1}{2}r$; that changes the left hand side of (2) into the expression for kinetic energy.
$$ \frac{1}{2}m v^2 = \frac{1}{2} k \ r^{p+1} \tag{3} $$
In going from (2) to (3) the change to the right hand side is particularly interesting:
The multiplication with $r$ had the effect of changing $r^p$ to $r^{p+1}$; the exponent of $r$ was raised by one unit. That is the same as what happens in integration of the force over distance.
Therefore:
For any force law that has the form of (1) we can treat the right hand side of (3) as an expression for potential energy.
Example:
Hooke's law:
$$ \frac{m v^2}{r} = k \ r^1 \tag{4}  $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}m v^2 = \frac{1}{2} k \ r^2 \tag{5} $$
Therefore in the case of Hooke's law we have:
$$ E_k = E_p \tag{6} $$
What that says is: if you have a bound system and the centripetal force is according to Hooke's law, then when you increase the radius of circumnavigating motion the kinetic energy and the potential energy will remain in a 1-to-1 ratio.

Next the inverse square law of gravity:
$$ \frac{m v^2}{r} = GM m \ r^{-2} \tag{7}  $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}m v^2 = \frac{1}{2} GM m \ r^{-1} \tag{8} $$
In order to treat the right hand side of (8) as an expression for potential energy we need to introduce a minus sign. That minus sign expresses that when you shift the altitude of an orbit the kinetic energy and potential energy are counter-changing.
$$ 2 E_k = -E_p \tag{9}  $$
(9) expresses the following counterintuitive property of orbital motion according to an inverse square law of attraction:
When a spacecraft is in orbit, and you want to descend you fire retro thrusters. The spacecraft descends, and potential energy is converted to kinetic energy. The original kinetic energy is more than replenished: in the lower altitude orbit the kinetic energy is larger than it was in the higher altitude orbit.
Quite likely you already know the following: astronomers use the velocity distribution of the stars of a galaxy to infer how much gravitational mass there is, and how that mass is distributed.

Thanks for sharing!

I think I have a proof without rotational motion.
$\langle T\rangle = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^N \langle \vec{F_k} \cdot \vec r_k \rangle$ ?
$\langle \vec{F_k} \cdot \vec{r_k}\rangle = \frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \vec{F_k} \cdot \vec{r_k} dt$
$\vec{u}=\vec{r_k}. du =\frac{dr_k}{dt}. dv=\frac{d\vec{p_k}}{dt}. v=p_k.$
Use integration by parts to convert this to the desired kinetic energy expression.
$\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \vec{F_k} \cdot \vec{r_k} dt=\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau \frac{d\vec{p_k}}{dt} \cdot \vec{r_k} dt=\frac{1}{\tau }[  
\require{cancel}\cancel{\vec{r_k}\cdot \vec{p_k}|_\lambda}-\int_0^\tau \vec{p_k}\cdot \frac{d\vec{r_k}}{dt} dt]$
Where the first term on the far right is $0$ since position and momentum have the same values at the beginning and end of a cycle.
$-\int_0^\tau (1/m_k) \vec{p_k}\cdot (m_k \frac{d\vec{r_k}}{dt}) dt=-2\langle  p^2/2m\rangle=-2\langle T_k\rangle$
$\sum_{k=0}^N -2\langle T_k \rangle =\sum_{k=0}^N \langle \vec{F_k} \cdot \vec{r_k}\rangle$
$\implies \langle T \rangle = \frac{-1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^N \langle \vec{F_k} \cdot \vec{r_k}\rangle$
